# Permutation calculator

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, math-software, gap, computational-algebra

I am studying the Mathieu group $M_{11}$ on the twelve letters $\infty,7,6,8,X,2,0,3,4,1,9,5$ (in this specific order) in the form that it is generated by the permutations $(0123456789X)$, $(13954)(267X8)$ and $(\infty 0)(18)(7364)(29X5)$ (as in Wilson, "The Complex Leech Lattice and Maximal Subgroups of the Suzuki Group").

Now I need to find two elements of $M_{11}$:

One element should take $8$ to $\infty$ while fixing the coordinates $7$ and $6$ as a whole (i.e. possibly interchanging them).

Another element should take $2$ to $\infty$ while fixing the coordinates $0$ and $1$ as a whole (i.e. possibly interchanging them).

Is there some way or a program which can be used for computing such permutations?

Comment: This group is [defined](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/groups/sage/groups/perm_gps/permgroup_named.html#sage.groups.perm_gps.permgroup_named.MathieuGroup) in SAGE, although I don't know if you can list all of its elements because it is quite large. It is also [defined](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap50_mj.html) in GAP.

Comment: I have also noticed that this group is sharply 5-transitive so that the elements above must exist (which is already sufficient for my purpose).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that there is a typo in the formulation of the question because the paper "The Complex Leech Lattice and Maximal Subgroups of the Suzuki Group" by R.Wilson gives $(0123456789X)$, $(13954)(267X8)$ and $(\infty 0)(18)(7364)(29X5)$ as generators for $M_{11}$ on page 153 (note also that $X$ and $8$ are in the reverse order in the question).

Anyhow, the question is "Is there some way or a program which can be used for computing such permutations?" and I will demonstrate that this is doable with [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org).

First I want to automate a little bit conversion from $\infty,7,6,8,X,2,0,3,4,1,9,5$ (in this specific order) to permutations acting on `[1..12]`:

This is a list of letters on which the group is acting:

```
gap> l:=[infinity,7,6,8,'X',2,0,3,4,1,9,5];
[ infinity, 7, 6, 8, 'X', 2, 0, 3, 4, 1, 9, 5 ]
```

This is a list of letters in the cycle notation for the 1st permutation  $(0123456789X)$:

```
gap> s:=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'X'];
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'X' ]
```

Now their positions in the list `l`:

```
gap> List(s,i->Position(l,i));
[ 7, 10, 6, 8, 9, 12, 3, 2, 4, 11, 5 ]
```

I am not really happy about the next step, because I am just copying and pasting the last output replacing `[ ]` by `( )` but one should be able to automate this too:

```
gap> u:=(7, 10, 6, 8, 9, 12, 3, 2, 4, 11, 5);
(2,4,11,5,7,10,6,8,9,12,3)
```

So, this is the 1st generator translated to an element of the permutation group acting on 12 points that we are going to construct.

Similarly, we have for $(13954)(267X8)$

```
gap> s:=[1,3,9,5,4,2,6,7,'X',8];
[ 1, 3, 9, 5, 4, 2, 6, 7, 'X', 8 ]
gap> List(s,i->Position(l,i));
[ 10, 8, 11, 12, 9, 6, 3, 2, 5, 4 ]
gap> v:=(10, 8, 11, 12, 9)(6, 3, 2, 5, 4);
(2,5,4,6,3)(8,11,12,9,10)
```

(also inserting extra parentheses for the cycle structure), and for $(\infty 0)(18)(7364)(29X5)$

```
gap> s:=[infinity,0,1,8,7,3,6,4,2,9,'X',5];
[ infinity, 0, 1, 8, 7, 3, 6, 4, 2, 9, 'X', 5 ]
gap> List(s,i->Position(l,i));
[ 1, 7, 10, 4, 2, 8, 3, 9, 6, 11, 5, 12 ]
gap> w:=(1, 7)(10, 4)(2, 8, 3, 9)(6, 11, 5, 12);
(1,7)(2,8,3,9)(4,10)(5,12,6,11)
```

Now we will construct the group acting on 12 points and check that this is $M_{11}$:

```
gap> M:=Group(u,v,w);
Group([ (2,4,11,5,7,10,6,8,9,12,3), (2,5,4,6,3)(8,11,12,9,10), 
        (1,7)(2,8,3,9)(4,10)(5,12,6,11) ])
gap> Size(M);
7920
gap> IsSimple(M);
true
gap> StructureDescription(M);
"M11"
```

Next, we will find an element of $M$ which swaps $8$ and $\infty$ while fixing the letters $7$ and $6$. We will use `RepresentativeAction` specifying that M acts on tuples, and give two tuples of positions of these letters in the list `l`:

```
gap> RepresentativeAction(M,[4,1,2,3],[1,4,2,3],OnTuples);
(1,4)(5,6)(8,11)(9,12)
```

Translating it back to letters, we have the permutation $(\infty,8)(X,2),(3,9)(4,5)$

Similarly, to find an element that should take $2$ to $\infty$ while fixing the coordinates $0$ and $1$, we obtain:

```
gap> RepresentativeAction(M,[6,1,7,10],[1,6,7,10],OnTuples);
(1,6)(2,9)(4,8)(5,11)
```

which corresponds to $(\infty,2)(7,4)(8,3)(X,9)$.

---

**Update:** As noted by @ahulpke, one could also just replace $\infty$, $0$ and $X$ by other numbers and leave all other numbers intact. This will make the translation to the notation from the paper easier. Indeed, let's use 50 for $0$, $66$ for $X$ and 88 for $\infty$. Then we have

```
gap> u:= ( 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 66 );
(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,66,50)
gap> v:=(1,3,9,5,4)(2,6,7,66,8);
(1,3,9,5,4)(2,6,7,66,8)
gap> w:=(88,50)(1,8)(7,3,6,4)(2,9,66,5);
(1,8)(2,9,66,5)(3,6,4,7)(50,88)
gap> G:=Group(u,v,w);
<permutation group with 3 generators>
gap> Size(G);
7920
gap> StructureDescription(G);
"M11"
```

and may then continue in the same way.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the mistakes.
However, I do not quite understand why it is the group $M_{11}$ and not $M_{12}$, since it is acting on twelve letters (this was confusing me a lot).
Is this just a group which is isomorphic to $M_{11}$, but acting on twelve letters?
Also thank you for the description of programming this (I had to finish my bachelor thesis that time and luckily found some needed permutations manually, but if I ever need it again, this program will be faster).

Comment: @lattice: you're welcome! Good that you've found a solution. You're right - this group is isomorphic to $M_{11}$ but acts on 12 points.